# Bash country code to emoji

Tags: bash

I'm trying to convert this JS code to a Bash script.

```
'US'.replace(/./g, char => String.fromCodePoint(char.charCodeAt(0) + 127397))
// it prints:
```

Here's what I did so far.

```
CHAR_TO_INT_1=$(printf '%d' "'U") # 85
NEW_CHAR_CODE_1=$(($CHAR_TO_INT_1 + 127397)) # 127482
NEW_CHAR_TO_STR_1=$(echo $NEW_CHAR_CODE_1 | awk '{printf("%c", $1)}') # ?

CHAR_TO_INT_2=$(printf '%d' "'S") # 83
NEW_CHAR_CODE_2=$(($CHAR_TO_INT_2 + 127397)) # 127480
NEW_CHAR_TO_STR_2=$(echo $NEW_CHAR_CODE_2 | awk '{printf("%c", $1)}') # ?

EMOJI=$NEW_CHAR_TO_STR_1$NEW_CHAR_TO_STR_2 # ??
```

But I get `??` in the terminal. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: try printing character code in javascript and bash and check what they output, also are you sure you have unicode support in your terminal?

Comment: If I run this `echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"`, I get ☠ in terminal. I think there's nothing wrong with unicode support. Problem might be in the 3rd line. If I run this `echo 85 | awk '{printf("%c", $1)}'`, it prints `U`, but if run this `echo 127482 | awk '{printf("%c", $1)}'`, it prints `?`.

Comment: it's because you cannot use `%c` for Unicode format, afaik `%c` relates to ASCII character and has 1 byte

Comment: @ozgrozer You’ll have to deal with the character encoding of the terminal (probably UTF-8).

Comment: @Biffen So you're telling me that there's nothing wrong with the code?

Comment: @ozgrozer No, that’s not at all what I meant. It’s just that once you have the *codepoint* (127482, i.e. 0x1F1FA), you’ll have to convert it into bytes as per the character encoding of your terminal (which, if you’re using UTF-8, would be `F0 9F 87 BA`).

Comment: You may convert it to a bash script, but don't expect it to display the flag in just any terminal. Unicode handling is rather limited, depends on the terminal, locale, etc...

Answer (score 2):

It's been 5 years. I don't know if you are still in need of the solution, but today I stumbled upon this problem and have found the solution, so I am leaving the answer for the future readers.

When you use `awk '{printf("%c", $1)}'`, Bash prints the Unicode regional indicator referenced by the **decimal number** as indicated by the variables `$NEW_CHAR_CODE_1` and. `$NEW_CHAR_CODE_2`. Bash accept only **hexadecimal codepoint value** to output a Unicode character, so decimal value won't work.

So in order to print the US flag, you can do like this `printf '\U1F1FA\U1F1F8'`, which are the hex codepoint prefixed by the string `\U`, so converting the two numbers 127482 and 127480 using printf string formatter `%c` won't work. What you need is to convert them into hexadecimal values using string formatter `%X` and add the prefix string `\U`. It can be done by `awk '{printf("\\U%X",$1)}'` or even simpler `printf '\\U%X' $CHAR_CODE`, the first backlash is used to escape the backlash character.

So you code above should be changed into something like this:

```bash
CHAR_TO_INT_1=$(printf '%d' "'U") # 85
NEW_CHAR_CODE_1=$(($CHAR_TO_INT_1 + 127397)) # 127482
NEW_CHAR_TO_STR_1=$(printf '\\U%X' $NEW_CHAR_CODE_1) # \U1F1FA

CHAR_TO_INT_2=$(printf '%d' "'S") # 83
NEW_CHAR_CODE_2=$(($CHAR_TO_INT_2 + 127397)) # 127480
NEW_CHAR_TO_STR_2=$(printf '\\U%X' $NEW_CHAR_CODE_2) # \U1F1F8

EMOJI=$NEW_CHAR_TO_STR_1$NEW_CHAR_TO_STR_2 #
```

The use of awk is unnecessary.

Or you can refer to my one-liner version:

```bash
country="US"
echo $(printf '\\U%X\\U%X' $(($(printf '%d' "'${country:0:1}") + 127397)) $(($(printf '%d' "'${country:1}") + 127397)))
```

Reference:

- printf format string https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

Comment: `echo $(printf)$(printf`? Just `printf '\\U%X\\U%X' $(($(printf '%d' "'${country:0:1}") + 127397)) $(($(printf '%d' "'${country:1}") + 127397))`

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited to improve the answer.

Comment: Or `printf $(printf '\\U%X\\U%X' $(($(printf '%d' "'${country:0:1}") + 127397)) $(($(printf '%d' "'${country:1}") + 127397)))`

Answer (score 0):

you should replace `%c` in `printf` for `%3s`, proof of concept:

```
 printf('%3s',$1)
```

Comment: If I use like that `echo 85 | awk '{printf("%c", $1)}'` it gives me the character `U` and I guess this is what I need for, but if I try like you said it just gives me `85`, the number value of character. So I need to convert this number `127482` to its string value.